# using ViewBag - asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a asp.net mvc project i have this on top of my index.cshtml file

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("getLoggedUser", "Home")',
    dataType: "html",
    "async": true,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {

    },
});
```

And the method it uses is this one, that is on HomeController

```
public async Task getLoggedUser()
{
    try
    {
        BenchesService benchService = new BenchesService();
        UserTest LoggedUser = new UserTest();
        string name = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        name = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        LoggedUser = await benchService.getCurrentUser(name);
        role = LoggedUser.role;
        ViewBag.LoggedUser = LoggedUser.role;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

This does a GET to the server with getCurrentUser(name); and that returns a json with user info, that i use to fill a UserTest object (i checked with break and the LoggedUser  is filled correctly).

I want to save the user Role, to use in the html / javascript part

Then again on my index.cshtml i have this other script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("TIMER!");
        userRole = '@ViewBag.LoggedUser';
        alert(userRole);
    }, 5000);
```

My problem is that the alert shows a empty message, like the `ViewBag.LoggedUser` has nothing. am i using `ViewBag` wrong?

Comment: `returns a json with user info` No it doesn't... You are not returning anything.

Comment: ViewBag can only be read at the server side. Return a json with logged user and access it in the success callback and you shoukd be fine.

Comment: i explained wrong, ill fix my post

Comment: `@ViewBag.LoggedUser` is razor code - its parsed on the server before its sent to the client so if `@ViewBag.LoggedUser` is `null` in you GET method that generated the view, it will alert nothing. Your ajax method calls a method which return nothing.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Use Strongly typed models and then actually return something from your GET on the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you reloading your page? If not, your ViewBag has the same content like in the moment when page was rendering. Razor render text from ViewBag only on creation of html page, and if you are not reloading page, it will be always empty. You have to return your data in some object (ex. json) to ajax request and then you can use it.